# Why can I not see in the distribution functions that t^2=F?

Tags: t-distribution, f-distribution

I keep reading that $t_{(v)}^{2} = F(1,v)$. Given the context that a t value was computed for a parameter of a linear regression, I was under the impression that there are two possibilities to determine its significance:

1. straightforward: use the t value on the t-distribution to do it
2. Using $t_{(v)}^{2} = F(1,v)$, so sqauring the t value to get an F value and then use the F distribution to determine the significance.

But I wonder why the following distributions don't look identical then. What am I not understanding or doing wrong?

`curve(df(x,df1=1, df2=10), from=-10, to=20, col="red")
curve(dt(x^2,df=10), add = TRUE)`

[image: F distribution compared to a t distribution that takes in x^2]

Comment: F-distribution is defined for x>0. It is square of t. You graph is over -10 to 20.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure if I understand it. Is it possible in a linear regression to compute the t statistic, square it, and determine its significance on an F distribution instead of the t distribution?

Comment: You're not drawing the density of the transformed variable in the second case. 

If $Y=g(X)$ for some monotonic $g$, then $f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) |\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)|$ (e.g. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables))

Answer (score 4):

The relationship between $t$ and $F$ distributions is as follows, if

$$ X \sim t(\nu) $$

then

$$ X^2 \sim F(1, \nu) $$

So if $X$ follows $t$-distribution, then $X^2$ follows $F$. What you are implying by your code is that some positive-valued $X$ has $t$ and $F$ distribution *at the same time*, what is not true.

You can easily verify this by simulation:

```r
set.seed(123)

xx <- seq(-5, 10, by = 0.001)
x <- rt(1e5, 5)
hist(x^2, 5000, xlim = c(-5, 10), freq = FALSE)
lines(xx, df(xx, 1, 5), col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

[image: Distribution of X^2]